# How can I get the "Nanobar" plugin to go to 100% once all resources have been loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble getting the Nanobar plugin to work.

I have used the code from the example found on this page http://nanobar.jacoborus.codes/

```
var options = {
  classname: 'my-class',
  id: 'my-id',
  target: document.getElementById('myDivId')
};

var nanobar = new Nanobar( options );

// move bar
nanobar.go( 30 ); // size bar 30%
nanobar.go( 76 ); // size bar 76%

// size bar 100% and and finish
nanobar.go(100);
```

The loading bar goes to 100% before the page has loaded all of its resources.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this great plugin work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Loading bars" on the web are mostly a waste of time. It'll be an approximation at best. It's virtually impossible to tell how long something is going to take to load from the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nanobar doesn't monitor page loading (unlike [Pace](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) for instance). Your code simply create a bar and grow it to 30, 76 then 100% length as soon as script have started.

To fit your needs, you must hook the sizing commands to some kind of loading events ([readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) or [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)) relative to DOM (document, images...).

BUT, using it with load events is very limited because you'll have no grain control of the current loading state of page ressources (the total size and the downloaded size). Even if you're monitoring each ressource individually, you can only count ressources and add a 1/ressources_count * 100 length value to the bar.

A workaround is to use ajax ([onprogress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress)) or fetch API ([alas progress monitoring is still a bit scary](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators)) to load ressources (scripts, stylesheets, images...) dynamically. A global progress bar will then be pretty accurate but you may be facing CORS issues, concurrent ajax requests limitations and big big work to load a full page mainly with ajax !

Some libraries are trying to automate the whole process but it's rather a nice and informative loading animation than a precise and accurate loading progress bar (except for async requests).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to thoughtfully answer my question.